# UDF inside UDF doesn't work (ByRef argument type missmatch)

Tags: vba, pass-by-reference, udf

I'm building a udf that uses another one inside but I receved a error "ByRef argument missing" in a iteration variable, I have this string "-60981--:54044,-60981--:54044,-60981--:53835,-60981--:53835," and I want to remove duplicated items, so I want to get back this string "-60981--:54044,60981--:53835," here is the first UDF, this is which I want to use inside the second:
**first UDF: GetJSON**

```
Public Function getJSON(JSONObject As String, ObjectNumber As Integer, GetBack As Integer) As Variant
' 0 = object and property
' 1 = object
' 2 = property of object
Dim CompleteObject As String
Dim ObjectsInJSON As Integer
ObjectsInJSON = Len(JSONObject) - Len(Application.Substitute(JSONObject, ",", ""))

If ObjectNumber <= ObjectsInJSON Then
If ObjectNumber = 1 Then
CompleteObject = Left(JSONObject, Application.Find(",", JSONObject, 1) - 1)
Else
CompleteObject = Application.Substitute(Mid(JSONObject, FindN(",",JSONObject, 1, ObjectNumber - 1) + 1, FindN(",", JSONObject, 1, ObjectNumber) - FindN(",", JSONObject, 1, ObjectNumber - 1)), ",", "")
End If
Select Case GetBack
Case Is = 0
getJSON = CompleteObject
Case Is = 1
getJSON = Left(CompleteObject, Application.Find(":", CompleteObject, 1) - 1)
Case Is = 2
getJSON = Right(CompleteObject, Len(CompleteObject) - Application.Find(":", CompleteObject, 1))
End Select
Else
getJSON = CVErr(xlErrNA)
End If
End Function
```

**second UDF GetUniqueTrailers**

```
Public Function GetUniqueTrailers(JSON As String) As String
Dim i, TrailersCounter As Integer
TrailersCounter = Len(JSON) - Len(Application.Substitute(JSON, ",", ""))
Dim ArrayOfTrailers() As String
For i = 1 To TrailersCounter
'here below occurs this error, in the i variable
If IsError(Application.VLookup(getJSON(JSON, i, 0), ArrayOfTrailers, 1, False)) Then
ReDim Preserve ArrayOfTrailers(i)
ArrayOfTrailers(i) = getJSON(JSONstring, i, 0)
Next i
'convert array to text
For i = 1 To UBound(ArrayOfTrailers)
GetUniqueTrailers = getuniquetraileres & ArrayOfTrailers(i) & ","
Next i

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

done, I have to do another one "concatenateRange" UDF, it just join each cell value =concatenateRange("a1:a100") for example, and I did modify this UDF:

```
Public Function GetUniqueTrailers(TheRange As Range) As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim tempRange As Range
Dim tempText As String

For i = 1 To TheRange.Cells.Count
Set tempRange = Range(TheRange.Item(1).Address, TheRange.Item(i).Address)
tempText = ConcatenateRange(tempRange)
If i = 1 Then
GetUniqueTrailers = TheRange.Item(1).Value & ","
Else
If InStr(1, GetUniqueTrailers, TheRange.Item(i).Value, vbTextCompare) <= 0 Then
GetUniqueTrailers = GetUniqueTrailers & TheRange.Item(i).Value & ","
End If
End If
Next i
End Function
```